# Please give an example such that $f^\sharp_x=g^\sharp_x$ for any $x\in X$ but $f^\sharp\neq g^\sharp$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Please give two morphisms of schemes  $(f,f^\sharp),(g,g^\sharp):(X,\mathcal O_X)\to (Y,\mathcal O_Y)$ such that $f=g$ and $f^\sharp_x=g^\sharp_x$ for any $x\in X$ but $f^\sharp\neq g^\sharp$, where $f^\sharp_x:\mathcal O_{Y,f(x)}\to \mathcal O_{X,x}$ and $g^\sharp_x:\mathcal O_{Y,g(x)}\to \mathcal O_{X,x}$.

Comment: Just to be clear -- you are considering the induced maps on the localizations (which is covered in Eric Wofsey's answer), and not the residue fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No such example exists.  We may assume $X$ and $Y$ are affine, since it suffices to show that the two morphisms agree on an open cover of $X$.

So we may assume we have rings $B$ and $A$ and homomorphisms $F,G:B\to A$ such that for each prime ideal $p$ in $A$, $F^{-1}(p)=G^{-1}(p)$ and $F$ and $G$ induce the same map $B_{F^{-1}(p)}\to A_p$.  Note then that the compositions $B\stackrel{F}{\to} A\to A_p$ and $B\stackrel{G}{\to} A\to A_p$ are equal, since they are both equal to the composition $B\to B_{F^{-1}(p)}\to A_p$.  For any $b\in B$, $F(b)$ and $G(b)$ thus have the same image in every localization of $A$, and hence are equal.  Thus $F=G$.